# Python - Adding attribute to descriptor

Tags: python, descriptor

I've this descriptor:

```
# Generic descriptor
class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, instance, value):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value
```

I would add an attribute 'modified' to check if an instance of descriptor is modified. Es.

```
# Generic descriptor
class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.modified = False
    def __get__(self, instance, value):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value
        self.modified = True
```

How I can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that in your `__get__` and `__set__` methods, you actually want to access `instance`, not `self` (`self` being the actual `Attribute` object).

Here is one way of doing it:

```
class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self.attr)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self.attr, value)
        instance.modified = True

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._f = 0
        self.modified = False
    f = Attribute('_f')

a = A()
a.f
=> 0
a.modified
=> False
a.f = 33
a.modified
=> True
```

Of course, this snippet can be improved in many ways, depending on what you're trying to achieve.